# Exam class: amsmath & multicol environment: unexpected \par warning

Tags: amsmath, multicol, enumitem, exam

Within the exam class, I'm using:

- amsmath
- multicol
- enumitem
- solution box

The code in the mwe compiles as expected, but kicks out the error shown below:

[image]

I'm stumped because I can't figure out which code line contains the error caused by  `\par`. The error appears to be harmless. But I would like to have no log errors.

Your assistance is most appreciated!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Change to fractional Exponents}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)

% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt[6]{a}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

%Prob #2
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{5}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$5^{1/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

%Prob #3
\task 
$\sqrt[3]{x^2}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{2/3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}


\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's *not* an error message -- it's a *warning* message.

Comment: @mico I remember you telling me this before. But I have several other exam class projects with no ```\par```. And I'm probably being a little OCD in not ignoring this warning. Thank you @mico!

Comment: Can you edit your query so as to remove or correct the claim that you're receiving an error message?

Comment: `\par`  is a blank line and your example shows many blank lines

Comment: you have one `\par` after `\noindent` which is very weird, what is   the intention of that?

Comment: @Mico Excellent suggested edit! As I'm fond of telling my high school math students, it's all about precision. Edit done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\par` is a blank line and your example shows many blank lines, removing them  removes the warning.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Change to fractional Exponents}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
%
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt[6]{a}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%
%Prob #2
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{5}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$5^{1/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%
%Prob #3
\task 
$\sqrt[3]{x^2}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{2/3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}


\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to respond and solving what was for me a very vexing problem. So basically every time I want a blank line (e.g. to separate the various each ```Prob #__``` in a worksheet -- helps me locate a given math problem), I should use ```%```. Simple fix but would never have uncovered it without your generous assistance!

Comment: Can you possibly suggest a better, more efficient method of identifying the **problem # in the code section** so I can quickly find, say, problem #12 in a 30 problem set to edit? Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath I don't understand your comment, the warning identified line 69 which is the end of  `tasks` so I removed all `\par` in `tasks` and the warning went, so it was fixed immedately even though I do not know that package